# Listing widgets in a GTK+ window

Tags: c, gtk

I have a toplevel window that contains a lot of spinbuttons.

Actually user selects how many objects he needs and after pressing a button the application provides some action.

Usually I'm using a struct

```
typedef struct
{
.......
GtkWidget *widget;
.......
} _GUI;
```

that conatains widgets initialized by means of gtk_builder_get_object(). After it I can get info from them.

But here I need to cover a lot (>50) of spinbuttons and also I need to set their properties (for example set sensitive option etc).

So the question is it possible to list all widgets of a toplevel window (there are boxes and expanders also) and somehow sort them by their type (GtkSpinButton, GtkWidget etc)?

I want to avoid direct pointing to specific spinbuttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the top-level window (a GtkWindow) is a subclass of GtkContainer, you can use [`gtk_container_forall()`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkContainer.html#gtk-container-forall), for instance, to iterate over the windows' children.

Then for each child, you can use GObject's API:s (for instance the [`G_OBJECT_TYPE()` macro](http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#G-OBJECT-TYPE%3aCAPS) macro) to figure out the type of each child. You might need to recurse, if you have your spin buttons in nested containers within the window.

Comment: Right, just use `gtk_container_foreach()` instead to avoid iterating over ghost widgets.